# A alguma forma de contagem progressiva ao limite definido por Hora, soar alerta

Tags: javascript

Que modo posso usar Evento alerta, agendando alguns horários

Pelo que se prepõe a realizar um lembrete diferente a cada hora do dia, emitindo um aviso

Suponhamos termos um [JSON](http://json.org/json-pt.html) nessa estrutura:

```
var horaJSON = {
    "Aviso":[
    {
        "data":"24/03/2018",
        "hora":"06:00",
        "dica":"Café no bule."
    },
        "data":"24/03/2018",
        "hora":"09:00",
        "dica":"Caminhada no parque."
    },
        "data":"24/03/2018",
        "hora":"11:00",
        "dica":"Preparar o almoço."
    },
    ]
};
```

Acima nós temos um *Array de Objetos* "Aviso" onde podemos usá-lo para iterar os eventos contidiano.

```
    alert(" Hoje:"+horaJSON.Aviso[2].data+"\n Hora: "+horaJSON.Aviso[2].hora+"\n Lembrete: "+horaJSON.Aviso[2].dica);
```

Então a pergunta é - *"Como vocês fariam esta comparação e validação?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma método que retornar a data e hora atual:

```
function DataHora() {
  var date = new Date(), hora = date.getHours(), minuto = date.getMinutes(), dia = date.getDate(), mes = (date.getMonth() + 1), ano = date.getFullYear();
  if (dia < 10) dia = '0' + dia;
  if (mes < 10) mes = '0' + mes;
  if (hora < 10) hora = '0' + hora;
  if (minuto < 10) minuto = '0' + minuto;
  return [ [dia, mes, ano].join('/'), [hora, minuto].join(':') ];
}
```

o método `DataHora` tem como retorno um array, sendo a data e a hora:

```
["24/04/2018", "04:19"]
```

crie uma variável para armazenar a mensagem atual e a anterior, para poder compará-las posteriormente evitando que o `alert` entre em um loop infinito:

```
var lembrete = '';
var anterior = '';
```

depois você percorre o objeto `horaJSON.Aviso` e faz a comparação entre a data e hora de cada item com a data e hora retornado pelo método. Caso seja verdadeiro, defina o valor da variável, caso contrário não faz nada.

```
horaJSON.Aviso.forEach(item => {
  if ( item.data === DataHora()[0] && item.hora === DataHora()[1] ) {
    lembrete = 'Data: ' + item.data + '\nHora: ' + item.hora + '\nLembrete: ' + item.dica;
  }
});
```

para finalizar, verifique se a variável `lembrete` não está vazia e se é diferente de `anterior`, se não estive vazia e for diferente, exibe a mensagem e define o valor de `lembrete` em `anterior`, caso contrário não faz nada.

```
(lembrete !== '' && lembrete !== anterior) && (alert(lembrete) & (anterior = lembrete));
```

crie um método e coloque o loop e a condição `if` acima nele.

```
function exibeLembrete() {
  horaJSON.Aviso.forEach(item => {
    if ( item.data === DataHora()[0] && item.hora === DataHora()[1] ) {
      lembrete = 'Data: ' + item.data + '\nHora: ' + item.hora + '\nLembrete: ' + item.dica;
    }
  });
  (lembrete !== '' && lembrete !== anterior) && (alert(lembrete) & (anterior = lembrete));
}
```

agora defina um intervalo de tempo para que o método seja executado:

```
setInterval(exibeLembrete, 1000);
```

#### Código completo

> Você pode ver o código funcionando em [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/dalajoguku/edit?js,console,output), basta editar as datas e horas que se encontra no objeto.

```
var horaJSON = {
  "Aviso":[
    {
      "data":"24/04/2018",
      "hora":"06:00",
      "dica":"Café no bule."
    }, {
      "data":"24/04/2018",
      "hora":"14:40",
      "dica":"Caminhada no parque."
    }, {
      "data":"24/04/2018",
      "hora":"14:41",
      "dica":"Preparar o almoço."
    },
  ]
},
    lembrete = '',
    anterior = '';
function DataHora() {
  var date = new Date(), hora = date.getHours(), minuto = date.getMinutes(), dia = date.getDate(), mes = (date.getMonth() + 1), ano = date.getFullYear();
  if (dia < 10) dia = '0' + dia;
  if (mes < 10) mes = '0' + mes;
  if (hora < 10) hora = '0' + hora;
  if (minuto < 10) minuto = '0' + minuto;
  return [ [dia, mes, ano].join('/'), [hora, minuto].join(':') ];
} 
function exibeLembrete() {
  horaJSON.Aviso.forEach(item => {
    if ( item.data === DataHora()[0] && item.hora === DataHora()[1] ) {
      lembrete = 'Data: ' + item.data + '\nHora: ' + item.hora + '\nLembrete: ' + item.dica;
    }
  });
  (lembrete !== '' && lembrete !== anterior) && (alert(lembrete) & (anterior = lembrete));
}
setInterval(exibeLembrete, 1000);
```

Comment: Pelo visto aqui não rodou no "*snippet*", mas tô dando uma estudada linha-a-linha da tua resposta.

Comment: Para que funcionasse, tinha que haver um `loop` infinito - então fiz um documento HTML com nome de: "evento.html" e, introduzi entre os `head` um `meta`. À saber: `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=evento.html">`. Isto faz com que a página ao se redirecionar, chama a si mesma, criando um `loop` infinito. Dai funfa que é uma beleza.

Comment: Na verdade foi um erro meu, na hora em que eu estava escrevendo, escrevi dentro de um método, na hora de colocar aqui eu removi ele. Mas veja agora como ficou.